# chrome-app won't recognize id's that work fine when run by the chrome browser

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-app

I'm converting a standard browser based app that's working fine to a chrome-app.

Once the page loads up, it has already hit an error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null.  This occurs after several hundred lines of JS have done their job but its the first time the code makes a reference to the document object, specifically document.getElementById('mainDiv').appendChild(...).

I can clearly see the div with the id="mainDiv" in the debuggers elements tab. Yet, document.getElementById('mainDiv') must be returning a null. Any attempt at putting in breakpoints fails as they are ignored. I've added them to the line that fails as well as to lines that lead up to it and breakpoints are never triggered. I've read some of the threads on SO and I'm certain the breakpoints issue is just a bug in the debugger, but not recognizing an id when I can clearly see it and the code when run in the browser works fine leaves me wondering what's going on. Is document in the browser different from document in the app version?

Any ideas?

If I choose "inspect background page", the breakpoints work but it still fails but in a different way. The elements tab does NOT show my html page, but the pseudo generated background one and I can't get the debugger to show my page at all.

Any enlightenment would be appreciated. I've searched and read what I could find, but much of the docs are clearly out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be accessing the `document` object of the background page, instead of that of your POS.html file.

Try this:

```
chrome.app.window.create('POS.html',{
    'bounds': { 
        'width': screen.availWidth, 
        'height': screen.availHeight 
    } 
}, function(appWin) {
    var pageWindow = appWin.contentWindow;
    var pageDocument = pageWindow.document;

    pageWindow.addEventListener('load',function() {
        // now use 
        pageDocument.getElementById('yourid');

        // instead of
        document.getElementById('yourid');
    },false);

});
```

Also to inspect elements in your page right-click anywhere in the app window and select `Inspect Element` (this works only when the app was loaded as an 'unpacked extension')

Alternatively you can navigate to `chrome://extensions` and click the page link next to your app entry.

[image: Image showing how to debug a Chrome Packaged App HTML window]

Comment: I see what you're driving at, but with one exception. I'm not trying to get an ID. The object that should get control is a function named "houseKeeping". It doesn't have an ID.  I wasn't aware that there was more than 1 "document". Now I know. Thank You very much.   No matter what I try I just can't get this markdown working properly.

Answer (score 2):

As lostsource mentioned, you're probably accessing the wrong DOM's document. You should think about the javascript in your app running in different global contexts, one for each page. There is (at a minimum) a page for the background page, and a page for each window.

Each of these pages runs in its own global context. This means global variables like `document` and `window` are different.

In the background page will be scripts which you load via the background manifest tag. When you open a window, it can also load its own script via script tags (make sure you do not use inline or block script tags, but use `script src="foo.js"`. See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

The code that runs in the callback to `chrome.app.window.create` runs in the background page's context, so its `document` variable is for the background page's DOM, which is usually empty. Instead you can make it refer to the window's DOM using `win.contentWindow` as lostsource suggested, or add a page.js file with the script in it, and include it from the page via a `script src='page.js'` tag.

Comment: Great information! I followed you right up to the last sentence. It's the transition of control from background to my window/code that is giving me grief.  pageWindow.addEventListener makes perfect sense. How do I refer to the function houseKeeping that exists in "my" window/document? I tried pageWindow.houseKeeping but that doesn't work.

Comment: After some experimenting, I got it.      function(appWin) {
         var pageWindow = appWin.contentWindow;
         var pageDocument = pageWindow.document;
         pageWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {pageWindow.houseKeeping();}, false);}  ------ I'll keep experimenting till I can get my brain wrapped around this.   I wish they had a place to practice this markdown as I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your call occurring after the load event, e.g. the JS called in a function set on window.onload?

Comment: Here's my background.js:

Comment: Here's my background.js:      chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
   chrome.app.window.create('POS.html', {
      'bounds': {
      'width': screen.availWidth,
      'height': screen.availHeight
      }
   }, function(appWin) {appWin.contentWindow.addEventListener('load', houseKeeping, false);});
});
Since I'm waiting on 'load', by that time my page should be available and all its id's known. The housekeeping routine creates a fairly sized fragment and then wants to append it to an empty div with an id="mainDiv". It's that id it stumbles on.